# Reshape list of lists of tuples to NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I'm quite new to python and am facing some problems that seems quite simple but I cannot figure it out.

I have a list of coordinates in that looks like that:

[(-80983.957, 175470.593, 393.486), (-80994.122, 175469.889, 394.391), (-80996.591, 175469.757, 394.595), (-81006.72, 175469.298, 395.527), (-81019.538, 175468.399, 396.847), (-81025.594, 175467.643, 397.395), (-81030.366, 175467.25, 397.858), (-81030.455, 175467.776, 397.886), (-81033.209, 175470.89, 398.192)],
    [(-81037.166, 175471.423, 398.729), (-81037.911, 175471.237, 398.764), (-81038.01, 175472.285, 398.533)],
    [(-81030.537, 175472.562, 397.951), (-81029.792, 175472.896, 397.842), (-81029.668, 175472.131, 397.895)],
    [(-80847.281, 175417.644, 378.2), (-80853.651, 175417.621, 378.781)]

and I would like to convert it into an array of of shape `(:,3)` so that each row contain 1 set of x,y,z coordinate.

I tried the basics np.asarray but it only return me the element of the last `[(,,),(,,)]`"paragraph" so:

```
[(-80847.281, 175417.644, 378.2), (-80853.651, 175417.621, 378.781)]
```

I also read about nested list and tried several technique to flatten lists but it gives me the same unsuccessful results.

I would like to have an array containing all these "paragraph". Do you have an idea how to do that ? And why it only returns the last "paragraph"?

I didn't find any equivalent lists shapes (if it can help I got it from a dxf file with the dxfgrabber function).

Comment: What's this mean? `an array of of shape (:,3)`? It's super unclear what you want to achieve here. Could you show us what you'd like to get in the end?

Comment: I want to have  this in the end:array([[ -80983.957,  175470.593,     393.486],
       [ -80994.122,  175469.889,     394.391],
       [ -80996.591,  175469.757,     394.595],
       [ -81006.72 ,  175469.298,     395.527],
       ...
       [ -81037.911,  175471.237,     398.764],
       [ -81038.01 ,  175472.285,     398.533],
       [ -81030.537,  175472.562,     397.951],
       [ -81029.792,  175472.896,     397.842],
       [ -81029.668,  175472.131,     397.895],
       [ -80847.281,  175417.644,     378.2  ],
       [ -80853.651,  175417.621,     378.781]])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want an array of shape `(n,3)` i.e. a length `n` array of length `3` coordinates. You can do this with a list-comprehension and the `np.array` constructor:

```
import numpy as np
l = [[(-80983.957, 175470.593, 393.486), (-80994.122, 175469.889, 394.391), (-80996.591, 175469.757, 394.595), (-81006.72, 175469.298, 395.527), (-81019.538, 175468.399, 396.847), (-81025.594, 175467.643, 397.395), (-81030.366, 175467.25, 397.858), (-81030.455, 175467.776, 397.886), (-81033.209, 175470.89, 398.192)],
[(-81037.166, 175471.423, 398.729), (-81037.911, 175471.237, 398.764), (-81038.01, 175472.285, 398.533)],
[(-81030.537, 175472.562, 397.951), (-81029.792, 175472.896, 397.842), (-81029.668, 175472.131, 397.895)],
[(-80847.281, 175417.644, 378.2), (-80853.651, 175417.621, 378.781)]]
a = np.array([list(t) for ll in l for t in ll])
```

which gives `a` as:

```
array([[ -80983.957,  175470.593,     393.486],
       [ -80994.122,  175469.889,     394.391],
       [ -80996.591,  175469.757,     394.595],
       [ -81006.72 ,  175469.298,     395.527],
       [ -81019.538,  175468.399,     396.847],
       [ -81025.594,  175467.643,     397.395],
       [ -81030.366,  175467.25 ,     397.858],
       [ -81030.455,  175467.776,     397.886],
       [ -81033.209,  175470.89 ,     398.192],
       [ -81037.166,  175471.423,     398.729],
       [ -81037.911,  175471.237,     398.764],
       [ -81038.01 ,  175472.285,     398.533],
       [ -81030.537,  175472.562,     397.951],
       [ -81029.792,  175472.896,     397.842],
       [ -81029.668,  175472.131,     397.895],
       [ -80847.281,  175417.644,     378.2  ],
       [ -80853.651,  175417.621,     378.781]])
```

Comment: Yes this is what I want to do!
but when I try it i get an error message:    a = np.array([list(t) for ll in l for t in ll])
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: @MaudGalletti What version of Python are you on? Under Python3, this code works exactly as in the answer. Make sure you copy it right.

Comment: Ok I found the problem! My list actually don't have the very first and very last square bracket that englobes it entirely and this makes python unhappy apparently.... (I edited my input list without the bracket in the question). Do you know hoe i could fix that? my list comes from dxfgrabber: l = polyline.points. I tried l = [polyline.points] but it just add a bracket everywhere....

Comment: @MaudGalletti Well that is not a data structure in Python and it is impossible that a method/function can return that.

Answer (score 1):

Given a list of lists input `L` with the structure as specified, you can flatten your list of lists and feed to `np.array`:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

res = np.array(list(chain.from_iterable(L)))

print(res)

array([[ -80983.957,  175470.593,     393.486],
       [ -80994.122,  175469.889,     394.391],
       [ -80996.591,  175469.757,     394.595],
       ...
       [ -81029.668,  175472.131,     397.895],
       [ -80847.281,  175417.644,     378.2  ],
       [ -80853.651,  175417.621,     378.781]])
```

Answer (score 1):

If I copy-n-paste your sample into a python session I get a tuple of 4 lists:

```
In [685]: [(-80983.957, 175470.593, 393.486), (-80994.122, 175469.889, 394.391), (-80996.591, 1754
     ...: 69.757, 394.595), (-81006.72, 175469.298, 395.527), (-81019.538, 175468.399, 396.847), (
     ...: -81025.594, 175467.643, 397.395), (-81030.366, 175467.25, 397.858), (-81030.455, 175467.
     ...: 776, 397.886), (-81033.209, 175470.89, 398.192)], [(-81037.166, 175471.423, 398.729), (-
     ...: 81037.911, 175471.237, 398.764), (-81038.01, 175472.285, 398.533)], [(-81030.537, 175472
     ...: .562, 397.951), (-81029.792, 175472.896, 397.842), (-81029.668, 175472.131, 397.895)], [
     ...: (-80847.281, 175417.644, 378.2), (-80853.651, 175417.621, 378.781)]
Out[685]: 
([(-80983.957, 175470.593, 393.486),
  (-80994.122, 175469.889, 394.391),
  (-80996.591, 175469.757, 394.595),
  (-81006.72, 175469.298, 395.527),
  (-81019.538, 175468.399, 396.847),
  (-81025.594, 175467.643, 397.395),
  (-81030.366, 175467.25, 397.858),
  (-81030.455, 175467.776, 397.886),
  (-81033.209, 175470.89, 398.192)],
 [(-81037.166, 175471.423, 398.729),
  (-81037.911, 175471.237, 398.764),
  (-81038.01, 175472.285, 398.533)],
 [(-81030.537, 175472.562, 397.951),
  (-81029.792, 175472.896, 397.842),
  (-81029.668, 175472.131, 397.895)],
 [(-80847.281, 175417.644, 378.2), (-80853.651, 175417.621, 378.781)])
```

`np.vstack` does a nice job of turning that into a 2d array:

```
In [686]: np.vstack(_)
Out[686]: 
array([[-80983.957, 175470.593,    393.486],
       [-80994.122, 175469.889,    394.391],
       [-80996.591, 175469.757,    394.595],
       [-81006.72 , 175469.298,    395.527],
       [-81019.538, 175468.399,    396.847],
       [-81025.594, 175467.643,    397.395],
       [-81030.366, 175467.25 ,    397.858],
       [-81030.455, 175467.776,    397.886],
       [-81033.209, 175470.89 ,    398.192],
       [-81037.166, 175471.423,    398.729],
       [-81037.911, 175471.237,    398.764],
       [-81038.01 , 175472.285,    398.533],
       [-81030.537, 175472.562,    397.951],
       [-81029.792, 175472.896,    397.842],
       [-81029.668, 175472.131,    397.895],
       [-80847.281, 175417.644,    378.2  ],
       [-80853.651, 175417.621,    378.781]])
```

A couple points of explanation

In most contexts, separating python objects with a comma produces a tuple (even without the ()`:

```
In [687]: x = [1,2,3],[4,5,6,6]
In [688]: x
Out[688]: ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 6])
```

`vstack` iterates on the input list or tuple, and turns each element into a 2d array.  It then concatenates them along the 1st axis.

```
In [690]: [np.atleast_2d(i) for i in x]
Out[690]: [array([[1, 2, 3]]), array([[4, 5, 6, 6]])]
```

In this the concatenate wouldn't work because the number of columns does't match; in yours the 4 lists contain multiple 3 element tuples, so become (n,3) arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually want to flatten your list?

```
import itertools

flattened_list = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(original_list))
```